# Update Single XML Node Value of XML Column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I want to update single value of XML Node in SQl Server

Below is the table structure

[image]

XML Structure

```
<PayDetails>
  <Column Name="FG" DataType="float" Value="7241" />
  <Column Name="SKILL" DataType="float" Value="3" />
  <Column Name="PI" DataType="float" Value="87" />
  <Column Name="MD" DataType="float" Value="30" />
  <Column Name="LD" DataType="float" Value="4" />
  <Column Name="WEEKOFF_DAYS" DataType="float" Value="4" />   
  <Column Name="NETPAY" DataType="float" Value="5389" />    
</PayDetails>
```

I want to update value of **FG** from 7241 to 8000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [replace value of...with](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx) keywords:

Try something like the following:

```
update tablename
set TransactionFieldDetails.modify(
'replace value of
(/PayDetails/Column[@Name="FG"]/@Value)[1]
with "8000"');
```

Comment: Good to know, never heard of it